# Python pygame not responding. Sierpinski triangle and problems with randint

Tags: python, random, pygame, freeze

The first problem that im getting is with my random numbers.  every other time i try and run the program i get an error with a random number.  The program worked and would make a sierpinski triangle every other time until i tried to add color into the equation now the display box pops up then everything freezes

```
import sys, pygame, random, math, array

####initializes pygame
pygame.init()

#####deffining all my functions
def verticiePos(verticies):
    for i in range(2):
        screen.set_at(verticies[i], (0,0,255))
def randV(verticies):
    v = random.choice(verticies)
    return v
def Show(delay):
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(delay)
def randPoint(h,w):
    yRand = random.randint(0,h-1)
    #maxX = ((w - yRand) * 2)
    xRand = random.randint(0, w-1)
    return (xRand, yRand)
def mainFunc():
    verticiePos(verticies)
    randPoint(h,w)
def colors(point, maxRed, maxBlue, maxGreen, bv, gv):
    howRed = (math.sqrt(point[0]**2 + point[1]**2) / maxRed) * 255
    howRed = int(howRed)
    howGreen = ((math.sqrt((point[0] - gv[0])**2 + (point[1] - gv[1])**2)) / maxGreen) * 255
    howGreen = int(howGreen)
    howBlue = ((math.sqrt((point[0] - bv[0])**2 + (point[1] - bv[1])**2)) / maxBlue) * 255
    howBlue = int(howBlue)
    return (howRed, howGreen, howBlue)

#####global variables
xRand = 0
yRand = 0
howRed = 0
howBlue = 0
howGreen = 0

#####Let the user choose the size of the display and setting screne
w = input("What do you want the width of the dcreen to be: ")
w = int(w)
h = input("What do you want the height of the dcreen to be: ")
h = int(h)
size = [w,h]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Project 1, Spierpinski triangle")

######setting up my verticies and all the functions i made
verticies = [(1,h - 1), (int(w/2), 1), (w-1,h-1)]

gv = verticies[1]
bv = verticies[2]

lengthOne = w
lengthTwo = math.sqrt(((w/2)**2) + (h**2))


if lengthOne >= lengthTwo:
    maxRed = lengthOne
    maxBlue = lengthOne
else:
    maxRed = lengthTwo
    maxBlue = lengthTwo 


maxGreen = lengthTwo

############################################
mainFunc()

point = [yRand,xRand]

iteration = 0
delay = 2

#######the main loop thats plots points
for i in range(10000):

    v  = randV(verticies)

    #colors(point, maxRed, maxBlue, maxGreen, bv, gv)

    point = (int((point[0] + v[0])/2), int((point[1] + v[1])/2))

    howRed = (math.sqrt(point[0]**2 + point[1]**2) / maxRed) * 200
    howRed = int(howRed)
    howGreen = ((math.sqrt((point[0] - gv[0])**2 + (point[1] - gv[1])**2)) / maxGreen) * 200
    howGreen = int(howGreen)
    howBlue = ((math.sqrt((point[0] - bv[0])**2 + (point[1] - bv[1])**2)) / maxBlue) * 200
    howBlue = int(howBlue)


    screen.set_at(point,(howRed,howGreen,howBlue))

    Show(delay)

    iteration = iteration + 1

#####the loop went really fast and was hard to see it coming into shape so i added this
    if iteration > 2000:
        delay = 0



#howRed,howGreen,howBlue
```

This is an updated version of the code that works i just need to clean it up now

Comment: i just multiplied all the colors by 255 to get the correct color set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with random:

You use `random.randint(yRand, maxX)` in `randPoint()` and sometimes `yRand > maxX` 
but `random.randint(a, b)` require  `a <= b`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

---

Problem with freeze ???

I have not problem with freeze but you have loop `for i in range(50000):` and it takes 1 minute to finish. At first run I thought that program freeze.

You have no event loop to get keyboard event and stop program with ESC.

---

Function `color()` always return (0,0,0) - it is black - so I don't see Sierpinski triangle.

**@EDIT:**

Sierpinski Triangle with recursion

```
import pygame
import math

class Sierpinski():

    def __init__(self):

        h = w = int(input("Triangle size: "))

        level = int(input("Recursion level: "))

        margin = 50 # add to size to make margin around triangle

        # initializes pygame and setting screne

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (w + margin*2, h + margin*2) ) # self. - to make accessible in all function
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sierpinski Triangle - Recursion")

        # offset to move triangle to middle of window

        const_height = math.sqrt(3)/2  # h = a * sqrt(3)/2 = a * const_height
        invert_const_height = 1 - const_height

        offset = int(h * invert_const_height / 2) # to move triange up - to middle 

        # main vertices A, B, C

        a = (margin, h + margin - offset)
        b = (w + margin, h + margin - offset)
        c = (w/2 + margin, int(h * invert_const_height) + margin - offset)

        self.screen.set_at(a, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.set_at(b, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.set_at(c, (255,255,255))

        # recursion

        self.drawTriangle(a, b, c, level)

        # main loop (in game)

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        running = True

        while running:

            # keyboard & mouse event
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False

            # move objects - nothing to do here

            # draw object & redraw on screen

            pygame.display.set_caption("Sierpinski Triangle - Recursion [FPS: %f]" % (clock.get_fps()))

            pygame.display.update()

            # frametime 

            clock.tick(25) # max 25 Frames Per Second

        # end program

        pygame.quit()

    #-------------------------------------------------------

    def drawTriangle(self, a, b, c, level):

        if level == 0:
            return

        ab = self.middlePoint(a, b)
        ac = self.middlePoint(a, c)
        bc = self.middlePoint(b, c)

        self.screen.set_at(ab, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.set_at(bc, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.set_at(ac, (255,255,255))

        self.drawTriangle(a, ab, ac, level-1)
        self.drawTriangle(b, ab, bc, level-1)
        self.drawTriangle(c, bc, ac, level-1)

    #-------------------------------------------------------

    def middlePoint(self, a, b):
        x = (a[0] + b[0])/2
        y = (a[1] + b[1])/2

        return (x,y)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sierpinski()
```

Comment: Ive been working on the program a little more and i found the main issue is with my random x value.  I have to make sure that my random point is inside the triangle and my original idea doesnt work and its screwing with everything if anyone has any ideas about how to get a random set of coordinates inside the triangle i think i can get it working

Comment: I made Sierpinski Triangle with recursion - see code in answer.